# Why do browsers and Node.js parse URLs with custom schemes differently with "new URL(...)"?

Tags: url, browser, uri

Different browsers and JS runtimes behave differently when parsing URLs with custom schemes (that is, non-[special schemes](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#special-scheme) like "http"). For instance, parsing "test://example" with `new URL('test://example')` produces:

| **Runtime** | **`url.hostname`** | **`url.pathname`** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Node.js 19 | `'example'` | `''` |
| Chrome 108 | `''` | `'//example'` |
| Firefox 108 | `''` | `'//example'` |
| Safari 16 | `'example'` | `''` |

Why is there this difference and are both parsings valid or are some of the runtimes not spec compliant?